# Strip a string from either one or two digits

Tags: python

I'd like to send Direct-To-MX mail. To retrieve the correct MX server(s) I use the following functions.

```
import dns.resolver  

def MX():
    domain = self.to.split('@')[1] # self.to is an email address
    mx = resolve_MX(domain)
    s = smtplib.SMTP(mx, 25)
    return s

def resolve_MX(domain):
    MXlist = []
    for mx in dns.resolver.query(domain, 'MX'):
        MXlist.append(mx)
    rand = randint(0,len(MXlist)-1)
    mx_record = MXlist[rand]
    return str(mx_record)[3:]
```

The resolver returns a **string** like `20 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM` or `1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM`. The digit in front of the MX server indicates the priority. This can be a double digit or single digit and here lies my problem. Because the dns.resolver does not return a tuple eg. `(priority, server)`, how can I strip the either single or double digit priority of the string. Right now I assume the priority will be a double digit number.

Comment: Split by space, then do a double check to make sure the split created digits in the first index of the list.  You could also easily just check the first two indexes of the string...

Comment: I am truly ashamed that I didn't think of this... Well, time to make a new account and start therapy in attempt to forget this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your string is separated into two parts by a space, you can do:

```
final_str = received_string.split(' ')

>>> print final_str
['20', 'ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM']
```

Furthermore, if you are going to be performing priority *comparisons* in terms of *numbers*, it is better if your priority number is an `int` rather than a `string`. For that, you can do:

```
final_str = received_string.split(' ')
final_str[0] = int(final_str[0])

>>> print final_str
[20, 'ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM']
```

Comment: Thanks, I am truly ashamed that I didn't think of this. I do not use the priority.